# HtmlUnit Synchronization with JS Executor thread

Tags: multithreading, htmlunit

Please bear with me as I am relatively new to Java and even newer to HtmlUnit. I would like to know if there is a way to synchronize the main thread with the htmlunit's js executor thread? The problem is that I would like to read element text values while ajax requests that update those values are run in the background.

Can this be done without modifying the HtmlUnit's source code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly if that's what you're looking for, but you can set, on HtmlUnit's WebClient, an [NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController.html), which will automatically transform all your asynchronous calls into synchronous calls. This enables testing your AJAX code without having to poll or sleep for an arbitrary time, hoping that the AJAX call has finished. It's not the solution for all cases, but it's often very useful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to write a simple real-time screen scraping code. I have an infinite (user-interruptable) loop in which I check the HtmlDOM for changes in particular nodes, and if I see such changes, I record the text values of some of their child nodes. However, sometimes it seems that the code in the loop is accessing the HtmlDOM while the background javascript is still updating the same nodes. This leads to crashes. I guess I could use a DOMChangeListener but would that still be synced with the background JS thread?